# ANT - Replace with ignore match

Tags: regex, ant, replace

I would like to check how to do the below perl line in ANT:

```
perl -pi -e 's/**OLD**/**NEW**/g if !/StingNotExist/' File
```

For example, if the file contains:

```
yair omer
yair oren
```

After executing,

```
perl -pi -e 's/yair/galit/g if !/omer/' file
```

the file would contain:

```
yair omer
galit oren
```

Comment: Can't you use [`ant exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task?

Answer (score 0):

You do not want to exec out to perl, it'll be slow and the logging/error reporting will not be as tight.  It will also hurt your soul.

You want the [relpaceregexp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task.

```
<replaceregexp file="file"
               match="yair(?!.omer)"
               replace="galit"
               byline="true" />
```